# ¿Cómo reemplazar punto y coma por coma en lista de diccionarios?Python

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de diccionarios como esta:

```
[
   {
      "id":7010,
      "keywords":"Adoption; family; filiation; family right",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-05-08",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-06-06"
   },
   {
      "id":7443,
      "keywords":"educación superior; derecho fundamental; derechos humano;",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-09-04",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-10-02"
   }
]
```

Busco reemplazar los `";"` por `","` que tengo en `keywords`como lo puedo hacer. Espero cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no se hacen tareas

Comment: Dale una mirada a [esta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) entrada meta y a [cómo preguntar,](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te serán útiles.

Comment: @V.Lorz gracias, lo reviso y lo tomare en cuenta para una próxima pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te entendí bien, creo lo puedes solucionar con `.replace()`

**`Codigo:`**

```
lista = [
   {
      "id":7010,
      "keywords":"Adoption; family; filiation; family right",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-05-08",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-06-06"
   },
   {
      "id":7443,
      "keywords":"educación superior; derecho fundamental; derechos humano;",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-09-04",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-10-02"
   }
]
```

Utilice un bucle `for` para iterar sobre cada elemento de la lista, y sustituye el dato del diccionario(`"keywords"`) por el `str.replace(old, new)`

```py
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i]['keywords'] = lista[i]['keywords'].replace(";",",")
    
print(lista)
```

**`Salida:`**

```
[
   {
      "id":7010,
      "keywords":"Adoption, family, filiation, family right",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-05-08",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-06-06"
   },
   {
      "id":7443,
      "keywords":"educación superior, derecho fundamental, derechos humano,",
      "fecha_envio":"2018-09-04",
      "fecha_aceptacion":"2018-10-02"
   }
]
```

Comment: No es la idea hacerle las tareas a la gente.

Comment: @Edengarth23 gracias amigo, intente varias cosas y no sabia como hacerlo

Comment: Siempre hay debate en si responder o no determinadas preguntas, especialmente las relacionadas con ejercicios dados por los profesores. [Esta entrada meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) es interesante y trata sobre este tema.

Comment: Se puede observar que el OP no ha investigado nada, si hubiera buscado en Google *como remplazar caracteres en python* habría obtenido bastante información. No todas las preguntas necesitan ser respondidas